# How to parse strings into hierarchy or tree in R

Tags: r, string, tree, hierarchical-data

Is there a way to parse strings representing groups into a hierarchical structure in R?

Say I have groups structured as follows:

```
"1", "1.1", "1.1.1", "1.1.1.1", "1.1.2", "1.1.3", "1.1.3.1", "1.1.3.2", "1.1.3.3", "1.2",       
"1.2.1", "1.2.1.1", "1.2.1.2", "1.2.1.2.1", "1.2.2", "1.2.2.1", "1.2.2.2"
```

We can naturally see that the 'highest' level is '1', followed by the two main splits '1.1' and '1.2', and so on.

Can this be parsed in R into a hierarchical structure, and the 'levels' easily retrieved (e.g. as above - if I want the second-highest level then R returns '1.1' and '1.2')

Comment: You should go after data.tree package : https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/72405_bfee2f2adf1e43c4937d6b1b1955a7f4.html
There is some data treatment to do to transform your data into data.tree, but the output worths the work

Answer (score 2):

## 1) igraph

We can convert `x` shown in the Note at the end to an igraph `g` and then igraph provides many operations on it.

```
library(igraph)
DF <- data.frame(parent = sub("\\.\\d+$", "", x), name = x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
DF <- subset(DF, parent != name)  # remove loop in root to itself
g <- graph.data.frame(DF)
```

### Parent

```
node <- "1.1"
setdiff(names(subcomponent(g, node, mode = "in")), node)
## [1] "1"
```

### Children of Node

```
node <- "1.2"
setdiff(names(neighborhood(g, nodes = node, mode = "out")[[1]]), node)
## [1] "1.2.1" "1.2.2"
```

### All descendents of node

```
node <- "1.2"
setdiff(names(subcomponent(g, node, mode = "out")), node)
## [1] "1.2.1"     "1.2.2"     "1.2.1.2"   "1.2.1.1"   "1.2.2.1"   "1.2.2.2"  
## [7] "1.2.1.2.1"
```

### Depth of each node

```
dfs(g, root = "1", dist = TRUE)$dist
##         1       1.1     1.1.1     1.1.3       1.2     1.2.1   1.2.1.2     1.2.2 
##         0         1         2         2         1         2         3         2 
##   1.1.1.1     1.1.2   1.1.3.1   1.1.3.2   1.1.3.3   1.2.1.1 1.2.1.2.1   1.2.2.1 
##         3         2         3         3         3         3         4         3 
##   1.2.2.2 
##         3
```

### Leaves

```
names(which(degree(g, mode = "out") == 0))
## [1] "1.1.1.1"   "1.1.2"     "1.1.3.1"   "1.1.3.2"   "1.1.3.3"   "1.2.1.1"  
## [7] "1.2.1.2.1" "1.2.2.1"   "1.2.2.2"
```

### Plot

```
plot(g, layout = layout_as_tree(g))
```

(continued after plot)

[image: screenshot]

We can also use package rviewgraph:

```
library(rviewgraph)
rViewGraph(g)
```

## 2) strings

Using `x` from the Note at the end,  we can apply ordinary string operations to it directly so it might not be necessary to transform the data at all.

### Immediate children of given node

```
parent <- "1"
pat <- sprintf("^%s\\.\\d+$", parent)
grep(pat, x, value = TRUE)
## [1] "1.1" "1.2"
```

### All nodes of given depth

```
depth <- 2
pat2 <- sprintf("^\\d+(\\.\\d+){%d}$", depth-1)
grep(pat2, x, value = TRUE)
[1] "1.1" "1.2"
```

or

```
depth <- 2
pat2 <- sprintf("^%s$", paste(rep("\\d+", depth), collapse = "\\."))
grep(pat2, x, value = TRUE)
## [1] "1.1" "1.2"
```

### List with one component per depth

Each component lists all the nodes in of that depth.

```
split(x, nchar(gsub("\\d", "", x)) + 1)
## $`1`
## [1] "1"
##
## $`2`
## [1] "1.1" "1.2"
##
## $`3`
## [1] "1.1.1" "1.1.2" "1.1.3" "1.2.1" "1.2.2"
##
## $`4`
## [1] "1.1.1.1" "1.1.3.1" "1.1.3.2" "1.1.3.3" "1.2.1.1" "1.2.1.2" "1.2.2.1"
## [8] "1.2.2.2"
##
## $`5`
## [1] "1.2.1.2.1"
```

### Parent of given node

We can omit the line marked ## if it is ok to have the root node be its own parent.

```
node <- "1.1"
parent <- sub("\\.\\d+$", "", node)
parent <- setdiff(parent, node) ##
parent
## [1] "1"
```

### Siblings of given node

Get children of parent and then remove input node from that result.

```
node <- "1.1"
parent <- sub("\\.\\d+$", "", node)
pat <- sprintf("^%s\\.\\d+$", parent)
setdiff(grep(pat, x, value = TRUE), node)
## [1] "1.2"
```

### All descendants of a given node

```
node <- "1.2"
x[startsWith(x, paste0(node, "."))]
## [1] "1.2.1"     "1.2.1.1"   "1.2.1.2"   "1.2.1.2.1" "1.2.2"     "1.2.2.1"  
## [7] "1.2.2.2"
```

### All ancestors of given node

```
node <- "1.2.1"
x[startsWith(node, paste0(x, "."))]
## [1] "1"   "1.2"
```

### Leaf nodes

```
leaf <- x[sapply(x, function(st) sum(startsWith(x, st))) == 1]
leaf
## [1] "1.1.1.1"   "1.1.2"     "1.1.3.1"   "1.1.3.2"   "1.1.3.3"   "1.2.1.1"  
## [7] "1.2.1.2.1" "1.2.2.1"   "1.2.2.2"
```

### Internal nodes

```
setdiff(x, leaf)
## [1] "1"       "1.1"     "1.1.1"   "1.1.3"   "1.2"     "1.2.1"   "1.2.1.2"
## [8] "1.2.2"
```

### Note

```
x <- c("1", "1.1", "1.1.1", "1.1.1.1", "1.1.2", "1.1.3", "1.1.3.1", 
"1.1.3.2", "1.1.3.3", "1.2",       
"1.2.1", "1.2.1.1", "1.2.1.2", "1.2.1.2.1", "1.2.2", "1.2.2.1", "1.2.2.2")
```

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to use `str_split` to identify the depth level.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
strings <- c("1", "1.1", "1.1.1", "1.1.1.1", "1.1.2", "1.1.3", "1.1.3.1", "1.1.3.2", "1.1.3.3", "1.2","1.2.1", "1.2.1.1", "1.2.1.2", "1.2.1.2.1", "1.2.2", "1.2.2.1", "1.2.2.2")


strings %>%
  strsplit("\\.") %>%
  map(~set_names(.x,paste0("DepthLevel",seq_along(.x)))) %>%
  bind_rows
## A tibble: 17 x 5
#   DepthLevel1 DepthLevel2 DepthLevel3 DepthLevel4 DepthLevel5
#   <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
# 1 1           NA          NA          NA          NA         
# 2 1           1           NA          NA          NA         
# 3 1           1           1           NA          NA         
# 4 1           1           1           1           NA         
# 5 1           1           2           NA          NA         
# 6 1           1           3           NA          NA         
# 7 1           1           3           1           NA         
# 8 1           1           3           2           NA         
# 9 1           1           3           3           NA         
#10 1           2           NA          NA          NA         
#11 1           2           1           NA          NA         
#12 1           2           1           1           NA         
#13 1           2           1           2           NA         
#14 1           2           1           2           1          
#15 1           2           2           NA          NA         
#16 1           2           2           1           NA         
#17 1           2           2           2           NA
```