# How to display a simple tree in R graphically

Tags: r, igraph

I have data such as:

```
in  out
1   3
2   3
```

This represents the following tree structure:

```
    1     2
      \ /
       3
```

Every tree will consist of sub-trees like this one, with 2 sources (`in`) and one destination (`out`). A slightly more complex tree is:

```
in  out
1   3
2   3
3   5
4   5
```

which represents this tree:

```
    1    2
      \ /
       3    4
        \ /
         5
```

So, the top of every tree will contain exactly 2 nodes, while the bottom will contain exactly 1 node and each level in between will contain exactly 2 nodes. There could be many levels. One final example:

```
in  out
1   3
2   3
3   5
4   5
5   7
6   7
```

which represents this tree:

```
    1    2                     level 1
      \ /
       3    4                  level 2
        \ /
         5    6                level 3
          \ /
           7                   level 4
```

How can I plot these trees in a nice way ? I can't use `ggtree` because the version of R that I have to use does not support it. I have looked at `igraph` and `graph.tree` but so far can't figure out how to do this.

If it matters, I would be happy plotting it upside down compared to how I have shown the trees above - or left to right.

Comment: Have you seen this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61618629/how-to-parse-strings-into-hierarchy-or-tree-in-r

Comment: @Skaqqs No I haven't - thanks for the pointer - I wlll check it out

Comment: `version of R that I have to use does not support it` so you're still using <3.5? https://github.com/YuLab-SMU/ggtree/blob/master/DESCRIPTION#L20

Comment: @raw yes I am using 3.4.4 and I can't update it.

Comment: in 4.0+, `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` is the default and `factor` can take duplicated labels, youre really missing out

Comment: @rawr yes I'm aware, and I usually use 4, but this particular machine is locked down and I can't update R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input is an edge list so we can convert that to an igraph object and then plot it using the indicated layout.  lay is a two column matrix givin gthe coordinates of the vertices and the matrix multiplication involving lay negates its second column thereby flipping it.

```
library(igraph)

DF <- data.frame(in. = 1:6, out. = c(3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7)) # input

g <- graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(DF[2:1]))
lay <- layout_as_tree(g)
plot(as.undirected(g), layout = lay %*% diag(c(1, -1)))
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks ! This looks very promising, but it's upside down, and the arrows point in the wrong direction. The arrows should point down in the trees in the OP.  I don't mind about it being upside down, but is there a way to control the arrow direction ?

Comment: Have flipped it and removed arrows so that it looks like diagram in question.

Comment: Sorry to bother you like this, but I have a follow-on question based on this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69621541/adding-text-to-an-igraph-in-r