# Adding Text to an igraph in R

Tags: r, igraph

I have the following code, thanks to the [answer by @G.Grothendieck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69620275/how-to-display-a-simple-tree-in-r-graphically/69620437#69620437)

```
library(igraph)

DF <- data.frame(in. = 1:6, out. = c(3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7)) 

g <- graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(DF[2:1]))
lay <- layout_as_tree(g)
plot(as.undirected(g), layout = lay %*% diag(c(1, -1)))
```

[image]

Now, I need to add some text to this plot based on this:

```
DF <- data.frame(in. = 1:6, out. = c(3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7), 
date = c('2019-11-01', '2019-11-01', '2020-01-01',  '2020-01-01', '2020-12-31', '2020-12-31') )
```

I would like to have 2019-11-01 displayed on one side of the top level (or even better, in between the two nodes on each level), then 2020-01-01 on the next level, and '2020-12-31` on the next, with nothing on the bottom level.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Why not label the edges? What is the expected output? Try: `g <- graph_from_data_frame(DF); plot(as.undirected(g), layout = lay %*% diag(c(1, -1)), edge.label = DF$date)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `date` to the graph object `g` as an attribute, and also plot a directed graph `g` but with invisible arrows, e.g., `edge.arrow.size = 0`:

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(cbind(rev(DF), date))
lay <- layout_as_tree(g)
plot(g, layout = lay %*% diag(c(1, -1)), edge.label = E(g)$date, edge.arrow.size = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) This looks really good, but it gives me an error: `DF <- data.frame(in. = 1:6, out. = c(3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7),  date = c('2019-11-01', '2019-11-01', '2020-01-01',  '2020-01-01', '2020-12-31', '2020-12-31') ) ; g <- graph_from_data_frame(cbind(rev(DF), date))`
   
`Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ""function"" to a data.frame`

Comment: @JoeKing In your code, you already added `date` to `DF`, then you should use `graph_from_data_frame(DF)` directly.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood correctly. You can just add text with coordinates. For example, coordinates 0,0 put text in the middle. You can just position any text to any location.

```
g <- graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(DF[2:1]))
lay <- layout_as_tree(g)
plot(as.undirected(g), layout = lay %*% diag(c(1, -1)))
text(lay[1,1], (lay[1,2]+lay[3,2]/2),"2019-11-01")
```

Comment: That's good to know, thank you, but I worry about doing this programmatically since the tree could be very large or very small

Comment: from object "lay" you can extract the coordinates of each node. You can make a formula to generate the positions between the nodes vertically. If I understand, you want to have it between NODE 1 & 3, so find the x coordinate for NODE1 and a mean value for y coordinate between NODE1 and NODE 3.

Comment: I updated the answer. So, the coordinates are based on the exact Node's location. If you have a bigger plot, I recommend creating a function.